# How to determine the minimum number of experiments needed to compute m-many k-local Pauli expectations?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, measurement, simulation

Say I have an algorithm over N qubits and I want to find the expectation value of an operator $O$ composed of a sum of mterms, each of which is the tensor product of some number of single-qubit Pauli operators:

$$
 O = \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i \prod_{j=1}^N \sigma_{\beta(i,j)}^{(j)}
$$

where $\beta(i,j) \in \{{0,1,2,3}\}$ determines the identity of the j-th Pauli operator in the i-th product in the sum ($\sigma_0 \equiv I$, $\sigma_1 \equiv X$, ...) and $\sigma^{(j)}$ denotes a Pauli operator acting on the j-th qubit. The goal is to determine the following:

1. What is the minimum number of circuit experiments needed to completely evaluate $\langle O \rangle$ (a "circuit experiment" means as many measurements as I want for a given configuration of measurement bases over  all N qubits)
2. How do I find the elements of the maximally reduced set of measurement bases that accomplish (1).

**Example a**:
$$
O = Z_1 + Z_2 + Z_3 + Z_1 Z_2
$$

1. The minimum number of experiments is 1.
2. The maximally reduced set of measurement operators is $\{Z_1 Z_2 Z_3\}$, which corresponds to measuring all three qubits in the Z-basis. From outcomes of these measurement bases, I can separately compute $\langle Z_1 \rangle $, $\langle Z_2 \rangle $, $\langle Z_3 \rangle $, and $\langle Z_1 Z_2 \rangle $ and then add the results to find $\langle O \rangle$. In general, I'm allowed to combine terms that have identical Pauli products on their overlapping subspace.

**Example b**:
$$
O = X_1 Y_2 + Y_1 X_2 + X_1 X_2 + Y_1 Y_2
$$

1. The minimum number of experiments is 4.
2. The maximally reduced set is $\{ X_1 Y_2 , Y_1 X_2 , X_1 X_2 , Y_1 Y_2\}$. Even though in the course of measuring $\langle X_1 Y_2 \rangle$  and $\langle Y_1 X_2\rangle$ I measured both qubits in both bases, *I cannot reuse the results from those measurements to determine $\langle X_1 X_2 \rangle$* because I lose any information about classical correlations in the outcomes of $X_1$ and $X_2$ (i.e. entanglement) if I try to combine their outcomes taken in two separate experiments.

So, given an arbitrary $O$ how do I find the minimum number of experiments and the corresponding maximally reduced set of measurements

Comment: I am confused with $O$, if it's an operator its expectation value depends upon the state/density matrix.

Comment: without restrictions on the possible type of circuit, I would argue that the answer is always one. If I understand what you are saying, you can always use a circuit that "spreads" the correlation over a big number of modes, and then a single measurement configuration is enough to fully characterise the output states. See e.g. references in https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.02436

Comment: @glS I'm skeptical about "spreading" the information around in this context (no-cloning theorem) but haven't read the full paper, but either way the goal here is to avoid ancillas and just prepare another copy of $|\psi\rangle$ if necessary.

Comment: Although if its easy to demonstrate that the answer is "1" for example b I would be interested in seeing that method

Comment: @forky40, how would you compute <z1 z2> from < z1 > and < z2 > ?

Comment: @MahathiVempati Its the other way around; if I measure the Z-basis bitstrings for qubits 1 and 2 in a single experiment, I can use that dataset to compute <Z1>, <Z2>, and <Z1Z2>. The notation is a little sloppy on my part, but this is what I meant by {Z1Z2Z3} as the maximally reduced set for example A (Z-basis bitstring outcomes for qubits 1-3 yield all combinations k-local pauli-Z products (k<3) )

Comment: @forky40, can you explain how you would do that too? As far as I see, assume the state we have is $a|00> + b|01> + c|10> + d|11>$, then <z1 z2> would give me $|a|^2 + |d|^2 - |b|^2 - |c|^2$ and to calculate <z1>, I need to figure: $|a|^2 + |b|^2 - |c|^2 - |d|^2$, how exactly would I do that?

Comment: Again it seems my lazy notation is to blame. For the state you gave, If I perform an experiment where I measure both qubits and record the outcome bitstring, with enough statistics I would compile a histogram that looks like {"00": $|a|^2$, "01" $|b|^2$, ...}. This histogram contains all of the information needed to compute <Z1Z2>, <Z1>, <Z2>. The number of histograms I need to do this (and their measureemnt bases) is what I meant by the "maximally reduced set of measurement bases".